# Random text masking in c#

Tags: c#

What is the best way to mask 3 random letters in a 5 letter word in c#?
For example, if input string is "12345" then I need to convert it to one of the following outputs.
"12***" or "1*3**" or "1**4*" or "*23**" or "*2*4*" or "*2**5" or "**34*" or "**3*5" or "***45"

Thanks!

Comment: what is desired result? should stars be shown in result?

Comment: Either * or X in the result.

Comment: did you check the answers?

Answer (score 2):

While i liked Mehrdad's approach, there seem to be a flaw there. It seems to have the same result always, due to the selection of indices after ordering. Inspired by the same, you could do the folloing

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var inputString = "ABCDE";
var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var randomIndices = Enumerable.Range(0,inputString.Length)
                              .OrderBy(x=>rnd.Next())
                              .Take(2)
                              .ToList();

for(int i=0;i<inputString.Length;i++)
{
    resultBuilder.Append(randomIndices.Contains(i) ? '*':inputString[i]);
}
var result = resultBuilder.ToString();
```

Output Samples on different calls

```
**C*E
A*C**
**CD*
```

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi Is it really? Did you measure? For such short strings the book-keeping that is performed internally may easily outweigh the performance gains on longer strings,

Comment: not for short strings just in general and big inputs

Comment: Will test both solutions and use whichever works better. Thanks Anu Viswan & Mehrdad Dowlatabadi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use random ordering and take for example first 3 then you can assign `*` to randomly selected `Ids`:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var s = "12345";
var result = s.ToArray();
var randomIds= Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(3);
foreach (var id in randomIds)
  {
     result[id] = '*';
  }
var stringResult = String.Join("", result);
```

One output:

```
"***45"
```

Comment: may be you can replace array with StringBuilder as well, so that I can delete my answer. This is better approach